# Issue with Bootstrap buttons not spacing properly in React application

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, jsx

I am currently facing an issue with Bootstrap buttons in my React application. I have a Pagination component that renders "Previous" and "Next" buttons, but I'm having trouble achieving the desired spacing between them.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my application:

```
import React from 'react';
import PokemonList from './PokemonList';
import Pagination from './Pagination';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <div className="pokemon-list">
        <PokemonList pokemon={pokemon} />
      </div>

      <Pagination
        gotoNextPage={nextPageUrl ? gotoNextPage : null}
        gotoPreviousPage={previousPageUrl ? gotoPreviousPage : null}
      />
    </main>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";

export default function Pagination({ gotoNextPage, gotoPreviousPage }) {
  return (
    <div className="btn-toolbar justify-content-between">
      {gotoPreviousPage && (
        <button className="btn btn-primary mr-2" onClick={gotoPreviousPage}>
          Previous
        </button>
      )}
      {gotoNextPage && (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={gotoNextPage}>
          Next
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.pokemon-list{
    border: 1px solid red;
    
}
```

I expected the buttons to have some spacing between them, but they appear to be merging together. I have tried adding the `mr-2` class to the "Previous" button to create some margin, but it doesn't seem to work as intended.

I have already made sure to include the necessary Bootstrap CSS file in my project, and I'm not aware of any conflicting styles or overrides.

Can anyone please help me understand why the spacing between the buttons is not working properly? Is there something I might be missing or any additional steps I should take to achieve the desired spacing?

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!